# Single Sign on for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have been trying to implement a WEB SSO service provider plugin for .NET web applications using C#. I will be using shibboleth Identity provider. I have implemented the same for java applications using OpenSAML library. I want to know which library is used to implement it in .NET applications. Any pointer or suggestion is welcome.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211431/how-to-implement-single-sign-on-in-net

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I saw this question before. I have the understanding of how single sign on works. What I actually want to know is if there are any libraries in .NET like OpenSAML in java which can be used to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no .NET libraries as I know. But there are some projects online you may take a look.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14309090/c-sharp-asp-net-single-sign-on-implementation) and [basic SSO.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429166/Basics-of-Single-Sign-on-SSO)

Answer (score 1):

[Kentor.AuthServices](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices/) (or [Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kentor.AuthServices.Mvc/)) for ASP.NET MVC applications is a basic SP implementation for ASP.NET MVC built on top of .NET 4.5. Install the package and add some settings in web.config - no coding required.

The functionality is currently quite limited, so if you have more advanced scenarios it might not be enough (but pull requests are welcome).

Comment: I saw this and installed it but I cannot use already implemented one. I have to implement it myself.

Comment: I'd be happy to know why you cannot use it to be able to improve it, if possible please add one or more issue on the [github repo](https://github.com/KentorIT/authservices) to describe the issues.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [SAML : A SAML stack](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-stack.html) .

and

[SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).

There are a number of libraries as above, both open source and commercial.

Or ( just for completeness ) you could go something like WIF --> (WS Federation) --> ADFS --> (SAML) --> Shibboleth