# Single user authorization

Tags: .net

I need some suggestion we have a project in .net visual studio 2008 ( 3.5 framework ). Now we are planning to move the project to the new version of visual studio 2019, to shift from 2008 to 2019 it is a huge effort. So we are planning to build new features in 2019 and run parallelly both the application.

My question is if one user logs in the first application and if we redirecting the user to some page that is available in 2nd application, how can we maintain single user authorization in 2nd application.

Comment: I would not recommend doing this unless it is temporary, because otherwise you would get stuck with the first version of your program and could not refactor it entirely.

Comment: Google for ".net SSO".  For example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049579/single-sign-on-for-net